# Prestashop - different prices for different ZONES

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, zone, zones, price

I have a case, using PrestaShop 1.6, that each product has a different price in each zone.

**Current solution:**

Set price for zone like a specific price per country for each country in zone - this surely works, but is quite unfortunate because:

*number of products* * *number of countries in zone* = *pretty big number for human-easy edit*

**Question:**

Is there a way how to set specific price by zone?

If not, is there an already existing solution on how to automate the above "current solution"?

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** in this case, it **can't** be done by altering shipping prices! - I really need to set price by zone.

PS: This is co-posted on [PrestaShop forum](https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/472457-different-prices-for-different-zones/)

Answer (score 1):

I see next possible ways:

1. If it is not "manual" prices, but dufference based on e.g. percent
   or amount value, create in `Price Rules -> Catalog price rules` rule
   for each country (it will not per product changes).
2. Use multishop with `shop = zone`, same products, different prices.
3. Develop custom module.

Comment: ad 1) the price is "manual" and can't be set by global rule, also it would still require a lot of effort to change it , can you please elaborate more on 2) ? That could mean a solution. 3) That of course I can, but I wanted to avoid recreating something that already exists - or is not needed.

Comment: in 2) I mean next:  you can use built-in multishop functionality, create different shops (and manage it from one backoffice) for different zones, e.g. like `us.example.com` (or example.com/us), `eu.example.com` etc. Then or auto-detect customer country (1.6 core have checkbox in preferences that allow you detect country based on browser/system language etc. ) OR use solution to detect country by IP  and redirect customer on right `zone-shop`. Multishop allow you use same products for each shop etc.

Comment: ok, but I need the price to change even when customer decides to tell us his delivery address (and that is different than currently chosed country) - I suppose this is not possible with multishop? Or is the shopping process synchronized between all sub-shops? (I am sorry I've never done multi-shop)

Comment: I still do not tried sync ordering process, but when you will enable "Multistore" option in backoffice, there will be available "share customers, share orders" options when editing "Shops group". So if you started process in one shop, you will can continue it in another. We still have "price" question, I mean for products that already in cart, if it will not change automatically... you can do some small changes to delete products and then add it again in new shop. It is like I see it, not one-final solution.

Comment: I checked the settings and there is no option to share products, just quantities and orders, I guess it will only allow to complete order with items from one shop in another shop ... didn't test it though...

Comment: products sharing it is notoption in settings, check Catalog. Also when you create new shop it propose you to copy products from any esisting shop to new